# How to grey out an option in system tray C#

Tags: c#, system-tray

The problem is quite simple: is there a way I can grey out an option in the system tray? I have seen greyed/bold out options in other programs I use, so additionally how do I bold any options.

Here is my current code:

```
    ContextMenu tray = new ContextMenu();
    tray.MenuItems.Add("Open", TrayClose);

    NotifyIcon trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    trayIcon.Text = "myBeautifulProgram";
    trayIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.program;

    trayIcon.ContextMenu = tray;
    trayIcon.Visible = false;
```

So it now looks like this (ignore the border):
[image]

Is there any way I can make this like greyed out or bold?

Comment: Set the tray menu item `.Enabled` to false to grey it out. You may want to use the long hand version (actually storing the `MenuItem` instead of just adding it to the items). Otherwise you have to search through the item and set its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call

```
tray.MenuItems.Add("Open", TrayClose);
```

returns a [`MenuItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem(v=vs.110).aspx). It has useful members such as [`Enabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DefaultItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.defaultitem(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can do something like this. Important part is to set your menu item's `Enabled` property to `false`. This is just simple code that shows how it works - you can make it more elegant than this I believe :)

```
 tray.MenuItems.Add("Open", TrayClose);
 tray.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
```